# Java Print on printer in columns

Tags: java, printing, multiple-columns, thermal-printer

I want to print on receipt printer in columns. 
I have tried to format the string before printing it with:

`String txt= "";
txt += String.format("%-20.20s %-20.20s %-20.20s\n", "STRING", "HERE", "1");
txt += String.format("%-20.20s %-20.20s %-20.20s\n", "STRING", "HEREE", "22");
txt += String.format("%-20.20s %-20.20s %-20.20s\n", "STRING", "HEREEE", "333");`

In console this was printed as it should, but in the paper in goes wrong.

Is any way how to print in columns in printers without padding with spaces?
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want three columns?

Comment: Your are right! My code was wrong. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: And how are you printing this? Using `String.format` with `%-20.20s` **will** pad with the space character (32) if the string has length < 20